# Does Markov chain imply that probability in moment n depends only on moment k even in cases like $P(X_n = x| X_k \in A, X_{k_1} = a_1, \dots)$?

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains

I'm trying to figure out is event in moment n dependent only on moment k even in cases where we consider multiple possible values for moment k? In formula I want to know if $P(X_n = x| X_k \in A, X_{k_1} = a_1, \dots) = P(X_n = x| X_k \in A)$ where ($X_n,n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$) is Markov chain, A is subset of X, $n > k > k_1 > \dots > 0$ natural numbers, $\{x, a_1, a_2, \dots\} \subseteq X$.

I was trying to prove it in this
[post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544881/how-to-prove-that-px-n-x-bigcup-i-1g-x-k-j-i-cap-bigcup-i-1) but still didn't manage to do this. Is this statement even true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: If its a Markov chain would the events in the conditioning only be relevant if they happened at time $n-1$? So if all of the $k, k_1, ...$ were less than or equal to $n-2$ it would just be $\mathbb P(X_n = x)$

Comment: @ilaK is it true? I thought that in Markov chain we consider some moment k as starting point and $P(X_n = x| X_k = a)$ not necessary equivalent to $ P(X_n = x)$ for any $k < n - 1$.

Comment: No sorry that was wrong, however it would only depend on the $X_k$ with the largest value of $k$

Comment: Well I wanted to know how to prove this. As I understand we have statement $P(X_n=x|X_k = y, X_{k_1}=a_1, \dots)=P(X_n= x | X_k = y)$, but can't see if this implies $P(X_n=x|X_k \in A, X_{k_1}=a_1, \dots)=P(X_n= x | X_k \in A)$ where $|A| \geq 2$

Comment: You can write $\mathbb P(X_n = x | X_k \in A, X_{k_1} = a_1, ...)$ as $\frac{\mathbb P(X_n =x)}{\sum_{y\in A} \mathbb P(X_k = y, X_{k_1} = a_1, ...)}$ source: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2967108/507703

Comment: @ilaK https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2967108/507703 implies that $P(E| E\cup F)$ can be writen like this, but $X_n = x$ is only in one side, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try and solve it in a more simply case first.

Suppose that $X$ takes values in a countable space and consider something like
$$
\mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-2} = x_{n-2}, X_{n-3} = x_{n-3}, ...).
$$
In your case the $X_{n-2}$ is replaced by the more general $X_k$. So right now we want to prove that only $X_{n-2}$ is relevant, we can do that by using the fact that $\mathbb P(A_2 | A_1) = \mathbb P(A_2 | X, A_1)\mathbb P(X | A_1) + \mathbb P(A_2 | X^c, A_1)\mathbb P(X^c | A_1)$ together with the Law of Total Probability as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-2} = x_{n-2}, ...)=&\sum_{\alpha\in\Omega} \mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-1} = \alpha, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2}, ...) \mathbb P(X_{n-1}=\alpha|X_{n-2}=\alpha, ...) + \mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-1} \neq \alpha, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2},...)\mathbb P(X_{n-1}\neq\alpha|X_{n-2}=x_{n-2},...)\\
=& \sum_{\alpha\in\Omega} \mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-1} = \alpha, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2}) \mathbb P(X_{n-1}=\alpha|X_{n-2}=\alpha) + \mathbb P(X_n = x | X_{n-1} \neq \alpha, X_{n-2} = x_{n-2})\mathbb P(X_{n-1}\neq\alpha|X_{n-2}=x_{n-2})\\
=&\mathbb P(X_n=x|X_{n-2}=x_{n-2})
\end{align}
$$

Do you see how you can generalise this?

Comment: I can't understand why 
$P(X_n = x| X_{n - 2} = x_{n - 2}, \dots) = \sum_{\alpha \in \Omega}P(X_n = x| X_{n - 1} = \alpha, X_{n - 2} = x_{n - 2}, \dots)P(X_{n - 1} = \alpha| X_{n -2 } = x_{n - 2}, \dots) + P(X_n = x| X_{n - 1} \not= \alpha, X_{n - 2} = x_{n - 2}, \dots)P(X_{n - 1} \not= \alpha| X_{n -2 } = x_{n - 2}, \dots)$ 

and not just

$P(X_n = x| X_{n - 2} = x_{n - 2}, \dots) = \sum_{\alpha \in \Omega}P(X_n = x| X_{n - 1} = \alpha, X_{n - 2} = x_{n - 2}, \dots)P(X_{n - 1} = \alpha| X_{n -2 } = x_{n - 2}, \dots)$

Comment: The equality $\mathbb P(A_2 | A_1) = \mathbb P(A_2 | X, A_1)\mathbb P(X | A_1) + \mathbb P(A_2 | X^c, A_1)\mathbb P(X^c | A_1)$ is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2378482/507703

Comment: Ok now I see, but I think you answered why probability depends only on largest k where we give only 1 possible value for k or why $P(X_n = x| X_{k} = x_k, \dots) = P(X_n = x| X_{k} = x_k)$.